How does one perform a tirtha?
What is a tirtha and how can one undergo a tirtha. Can we carry money and mobile phones with us during the tirtha. What is the dress code. In what manner one should do a tirtha to burn all his bad karmas of his present and past lives so that we do don’t face any bad consequences in our lives? What are some of the places where one can go to tirtha ?
